# Does shared memory absolutely need manual locks?

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, shared-memory

I have a raspberry pi that fetches different sensor data over I2C and SPI. I need to do multiple stuff with the same data, like visualization, database, and control. I want to keep it lean and get the data as fast as possible.

1. Does shared memory needs semaphores or mutexes to be used, or is it already handled by the Linux kernel? If I have 64bit data type, I must ensure that the whole 64bit is written when I read it.
2. What if the writer waits for a semaphore and think he can access it but a reader takes it right before the writer takes it?
3. Do anyone have a state of the art example on this?
4. Is there a good enough way, Faster and leaner than MQTT to do this?

I've looked into MQTT, but on program cannot subscribe and receive at a desired frequency, and I don't want my programs to be interrupted for nothing. I also don't want data to be written on the drive since EMMC and SD cards are do not have good R/W endurance.

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently you've never taken an operating systems course and/or exposed to the [dining philosophers problem](https://www.scaler.com/topics/operating-system/dining-philosophers-problem-in-os/). Why do you have an aversion to "*semaphores or mutexes*"? Why are you even looking at MQTT for a problem of contention among local processes? If latency is not a concern, then *token passing* is a possible alternative to *locks* for *mutual exclusion*.

Comment: You specifically mention "*shared memory*", which needs some form of mutual exclusion. The Linux man page for **shm_overview(7)** suggests the use of semaphores. There are other constructs for interprocess communication (such as pipes and sockets) for which Linux will provide the mutual exclusion.

Comment: @sawdust No, not everybody has taken every course that exists, but I am familiar with the dining philosophers. I don't have an aversion to semaphores, I just wanted to have more knowledge on what happens in the kernel. Latency is important for control loops that I have. I looked into MQTT because it's another IPC where everyone has access to everything and I only have one writer, but unfortunately the processes can't decides the frequency of receives. I'm interested in token passing, but can't seem to find good implementation examples. Do you have a source?